# Is there any other way to upload custom files or documents to sharepoint online from a web part or page?

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint

i have tried various java scripts but the files/documents are not getting uploaded to office 365 share point online but the script is getting interupted in between before alert on chinna suresh2

```html
<div onkeydown="javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13) _SFSUBMIT_">
<script>
$(document).ready(function ()
{
//alert("chinna");
    // Get the URI decoded host web URL
    // We will use this to get a context here to write data
    var hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("https://myit.sharepoint.com/sites/forms7/JSOM%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx"));
});
 
function CreateFile()
{
alert("chinna");
    // Ensure the HTML5 FileReader API is supported
    if (window.FileReader)
    {
        var input = document.getElementById("inputFile");
        if (input)
        {
            var file = input.files[0];
            var fr = new FileReader();
alert("chinna");
//receivedBinary();
            fr.onload = receivedBinary;
            fr.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        alert("The HTML5 FileSystem APIs are not fully supported in this browser.");
    }
}
 
// Callback function for onload event of FileReader
function receivedBinary()
{
alert("chinnasuresh");
    // Get the ClientContext for the app web
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    // Use the host web URL to get a parent context - this allows us to get data from the parent
    var parentCtx = new SP.AppContextSite(clientContext, hostweburl);
    var parentWeb = parentCtx.get_web();
    var parentList = parentWeb.get_lists().getByTitle("Documents");
 alert("chinnasuresh1");
    var fileCreateInfo = new SP.FileCreationInformation();
    fileCreateInfo.set_url(file.name);
    fileCreateInfo.set_overwrite(true);
    fileCreateInfo.set_content(new SP.Base64EncodedByteArray());
 
    // Read the binary contents of the base 64 data URL into a Uint8Array
    // Append the contents of this array to the SP.FileCreationInformation
    var arr = convertDataURIToBinary(this.result);
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
    {
        fileCreateInfo.get_content().append(arr[i]);
    }
 
    // Upload the file to the root folder of the document library
    this.newFile = parentList.get_rootFolder().get_files().add(fileCreateInfo);
 
    clientContext.load(this.newFile);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFailure);
}
 
function onSuccess()
{
    // File successfully uploaded
    alert("Success!");
}
 
function onFailure()
{
    // Error occurred
    alert("Request failed: " + arguments[1].get_message());
}
 
// Utility function to remove base64 URL prefix and store base64-encoded string in a Uint8Array
// Courtesy: https://gist.github.com/borismus/1032746
function convertDataURIToBinary(dataURI)
{
    var BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,';
    var base64Index = dataURI.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) + BASE64_MARKER.length;
    var base64 = dataURI.substring(base64Index);
    var raw = window.atob(base64);
    var rawLength = raw.length;
    var array = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));
 
    for (i = 0; i < rawLength; i++)
    {
        array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return array;
}
</script>
<input id="inputFile" type="file" />
<input id="uploadDocumentButton" type="Button" value="Upload Document" onclick="CreateFile()"/>
</div>
```

and also i have another script even it is stopping in between .can some one help me in executing the whole script

```html
<div onkeydown="javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13) _SFSUBMIT_">
<input id="inputFile" type="file" />
<input id="uploadDocumentButton" type="Button" value="Upload Document"/>
<script>
$("#uploadDocumentButton").click(function ()
{
 if (document.getElementById("inputFile").files.length === 0) {
        alert("Select a file!");
        return;
    }
var parts = document.getElementById("inputFile").value.split("\\");
    var filename = parts[parts.length - 1];
    var file = document.getElementById("inputFile").files[0];
});
var getFileBuffer = function (file) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
    };
    reader.onerror = function (e) {
        deferred.reject(e.target.error);
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    return deferred.promise();
};
"use strict";
alert(1);
var WingtipToys = window.WingtipToys || {};
WingtipToys.Jsom = WingtipToys.Jsom || {};
 
WingtipToys.Jsom.Libs = function () {
 
    var deferreds = new Array(),
 
    upload = function (serverRelativeUrl, filename, file) {
        deferreds[deferreds.length] = $.Deferred();
 
        getFileBuffer(file).then(
            function (buffer) {
                var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
                var content = new SP.Base64EncodedByteArray(); //base64 encoding
                for (var b = 0; b < bytes.length; b++) {
                    content.append(bytes[b]);
                }
                var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                var createInfo = new SP.FileCreationInformation();
                createInfo.set_content(content); //setting the content of the new file
                createInfo.set_overwrite(true);
                createInfo.set_url(filename);
                this.files = ctx.get_web().getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(serverRelativeUrl).get_files();
                ctx.load(this.files);
                this.files.add(createInfo);
                ctx.executeQueryAsync(
                    Function.createDelegate(this,
                        function () { deferreds[deferreds.length - 1].resolve(this.files); }),
                    Function.createDelegate(this,
                        function (sender, args) { deferreds[deferreds.length - 1].reject(sender, args); }));
            },
            function (err) {
                deferreds[deferreds.length - 1].reject(err);
            }
         );
 
        return deferreds[deferreds.length - 1].promise();
 
    },
 
    getFileBuffer = function (file) {
alert("suresh");
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
    };
    reader.onerror = function (e) {
        deferred.reject(e.target.error);
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    return deferred.promise();
};
    
    return (upload);
   
 
}();
WingtipToys.Jsom.Libs.upload("https://myit.sharepoint.com/sites/forms7/JSOM%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx", filename, file).then(    function (files) {
        alert("Uploaded successfully");
    },
    function (sender, args) {
        alert(args.get_message());
    }
);


 </script>
</div>
```

Thanks & Regards,
Suresh gaddam